# SQL - how to select words with certain values at the end of word

Tags: sql, select

iam new to sql and i would like to know how can I  find the letter or symbol at the end of value in column called `Name`? 
E.g if i would find  something  i will write `select * from 'table' where 'Name' like '%es%'` but it will find me all rows contains `es`
Lets say - `lesl, pespe, mess`... but how to write select which will select just values with  `'es'` At the end of word? ...   using `regex` i will use  `es\Z`..... thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are new, you might want to learn some basics before you start doing real work.  To that end, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in Ten Minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  i will find this book and  will be better and better :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to remove the last `%`, so it will only select words *ending* with `es`.

```
select * from table where Name like '%es'
```

Comment: Thanky for your answer. It was helpful :)

Answer (score 7):

You're currently matching on:  `..where 'Name' like '%es%'`.

Which equates to `anything, then 'es' then anything else`.

Removing the last `%` changes the where to 
`anything then 'es'`.

in short.. you need `..where 'Name' like '%es'`

Answer (score 4):

The query ..where 'Name' like '%es' will find columns where name ends with "ES". 
But if we need to find column where name ends with either "E" or "S", the query would be

.. where 'Name' LIKE '%[ES]'

Answer (score 1):

You can also use REGEX

```
select distinct city from station where city REGEXP '[aeiou]$';
```

Resources: [To Know more about REGEXP](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want to find name start with something like 'test'
   use => select name from table where name like 'test%'.
2. if you want to find name end with something like 'test'
   use => select name from table where name like '%test'.
3. if you want to find name start with s and end with h 
   use => select name from table where name like 's%'and name like '%h' or simply select name from table where name like 's%h'.

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern [a-z]ed($) with regexp operator/function.

Pattern explanation:

[a-z] - match any letter

es - match es literally

($) - end of string (so make sure it's not followed by any letters)

Full query would be:

```
select * from test 
where ingr regexp '[a-z]es($)'
```